# Windows 7 SP/1: restoring system to healthy state after recovery

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a tool that compares files on the Win 7 installation disk and the current system state of a computer installation - and repairs files which are corrupted (like the dism /restorehealth in Win 8 I think).

Does this exist?

In the situation I have recovered the system to a new boot disk from a SSD with many sector errors, so stabilised the situation and generated a functioning but damaged system (sfc irrecoverable errors, etc). I need to check and repair the system without performing a re-install, preferably using info on the original install disk (it is a complex system structure with many legacy programs and a largely hand-written registry, so a re-install is not an option).

Comment: Recommend using a key finder program to get your windows 7 key, in case the SSD completely dies. I'd also recommend doing a complete windows reinstall every time something goes this wrong on windows... I've spent a lot of time trawling forums looking for solutions for a menagerie of windows problems, the answer is always reinstall

Comment: You mean like `sfc /scannow`?  Never heard of a "hand written registry" the dism command also exists for Windows 7.

Comment: @ClothSword - Its always possible to resolve problems like this just a matter of how much effort you want to put in it.  Reinstallation isn't an option in this case, or should be the last option, after all other options have proven not to work.

Comment: @Ramhound I found that with Linux its ~4h reinstall everything or ~2h forums learning new things about linux which will benefit you in the future; whereas with Windows its ~4h reinstall everything or 40h trawling forums troubleshooting one problem which you almost certainly won't encounter again =p But horses for courses

Answer (score 3):

The alternative to `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` in Windows 7 is [System Update Readiness tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821) as described by Microsoft. Download corresponding version to your Windows edition and run it, then run `sfc /scannow` to fix the system files.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Windows System File Checker.  It's prebuilt into the OS so all you need to do is open a command prompt and run:

```
SFC /scannow
```

You can read more about that program and its options on this site:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true

Microsofts KD (including screenshot's and a how to):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Or you can use the Fix it Center from Microsoft:

http://fixitcenter.support.microsoft.com/Portal/

Any 3rd party application would have a half life of about 1 week due to Microsofts update schedule.

Comment: Yes, as written in the original post the usability of sfc was rapidly exhausted. If sfc and M$'s restore functions had worked I would not have needed to write my question...

Comment: Your next best bet is either the Microsoft Fix it Center (which I updated the answer to include) or reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the fix it centre - I think that has potential - unfortunately the beta is closed for Win 7 users :(.

Comment: @Talyinka - Use the non-Beta website then?  Mr. Fixit solutions have been offered for years.  Besides the website says it supports Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given it's a system corruption problem (OR SUSPECTED) A RESTORE is hands down the best bet (and quickest).
2. SFC and DISM do not fix all problems.....in fact (for many of us they simply supply a bit list of things they could not fix)  and it can take hours to track down solutions.  (how time does fly).
3. If you can't get into your system at all then hopefully the "repair windows" option on your "media" can help solve that issue (but it is almost never the only issue).
4. If that fails and you do not have a system clone (AOMEI or other) then a reinstall is your only (time effective) solution despite the length of time it takes to reinstall the MS monster and your apps and data assuming you have a back of at least downloads, the desktop, received files and documents.

As they say.....been there done that (too many times).